# How to un-scrape first x number of p tag in a div and print rest of them?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm have been spending past few days in learning of python. Today I come with a topic called web scraping. I'm trying to **scrape** all p tag inside a div except first 3 p tag. Since there is no class or id for the p tag I can't find way to un-scrape them

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div class="one">
    <p style="color:red">Dummy Text</p>
    <p style="color:red">Unwanted Text</p>
    <p style="color:red">No Text</p>
    <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p style="color:red">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
    <p style="color:red">consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
    <p style="color:red">ut labore et dolore magna</p>
</div>'''

text = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for result in text.find_all('p'):
    print(result.get_text())
```

My output:

- Dummy Text
- Unwanted Text
- No Text
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
- sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
- consectetur adipiscing elit
- ut labore et dolore magna

What I required:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
- sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
- consectetur adipiscing elit
- ut labore et dolore magna

Since I'm new to SOF please mention in comment if I violated any of the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the div strings to an array to store them. You should then remove the first three elements of the array. This can be done like this:

```
text = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
p_list = []
for result in text.find_all('p'):
    p_list.append(result.get_text())
# this selects all elements from the list after the third
p_list = p_list[3:]
```

This will give you a list containing all of your p elements except the first three.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Find all `p` tag and index based on your requirement

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all("p")[3:]
```

**Method 2:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
data=soup.select_one("div > p:nth-of-type(2)")
data.find_next().find_next_siblings()
```

Breakdown of code:

first use `select_one` method and find p tag using css selector in which `data` returns
`<p style="color:red">No Text</p>`

In last line we will find all next element with its siblings

**Output  (Same for both Metthod):**

```
[<p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>,
 <p style="color:red">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>,
 <p style="color:red">consectetur adipiscing elit</p>,
 <p style="color:red">ut labore et dolore magna</p>]
```